# How can I make self-updating chart with formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to make a self updating chart for weekly sales KPI.
[image: !https://imgur.com/a/KWxh3SZ]

Columns are the times, every day, by hand I update it until that time.

First row is the target, and then all the inputs are typed in by hand when we know how much we sold.

I need the chart to update itself by taking into account what time it's now. E.g. If it's Monday 13:00, then it means chart will only look into 5 inputs. I hope it's clear.

Green circle is % of how many goals we met, red circle would be how many goals were not met. Ignore the blue one.

Comment: You can create a dynamic named range and use that range in your chart series. [Jon Peltier's website](https://peltiertech.com/dynamic-charts/) has tons of good examples you can use to learn what you need. Start building your solution using that information and come back here with questions when you get stuck.

Comment: alternatively, create a new data table which will dynamically look up the values from the original table by given time, and create charts from the new data table instead.

Comment: I would then use a cell with data validation to be able to pick between current and previous...